# Prevent IOS autofocus first input when page opens ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, keyboard, ionic-framework

There is a page in our app that has a single input field. When going to that state on IOS, the keyboard automatically pops up. This is not what is desired. This doesn't happen on the Android version.

I've tried all sorts of things, but nothing is sorting it. My last attempt was to call `$cordovaKeyboard.close()` in the app.js run block within a `$stateChangeSuccess` handler. Alas, nothing.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

There's not much to put in code terms. The offending input:

```
<ion-item class="item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper bg-light-grey-30 text-center">
    <input type="text" class="text-center tracker" ng-model="values.exploreSearch" placeholder="Enter city, street, username or keyword"/>
  </label>
</ion-item>
```

And the JS in the `$ionicPlatform.ready` block in the main app.js run block:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  if (window.cordova && $cordovaKeyboard.isVisible) {
    $cordovaKeyboard.close();
  }
});
```

I previously tried putting a block in the page controller that looked like this:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  if (window.cordova && $cordovaKeyboard.isVisible) {
    $cordovaKeyboard.close();
  }
}]);
```

This last block, according to my client (as I don't have an IOS device to test on), worked the first time the page loaded, but not subsequently. If you left the page, and came back, the keyboard would pop up.

Comment: Couldn't you just add `$cordovaKeyboard.close();` in the controller of that specific page?

Comment: Or maybe make use of `ngFocus` to close keyboard? See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus

Comment: @MarkVeenstra That's what I did in the final code example block, just wrapped in the `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback.

Perhaps the ngFocus thing might work....

Comment: `$ionicPlatform.ready` isn't the controller. The platform ready could be fired before the view is loaded.

Comment: I put the `$ionicPlatform` call in the page controller.

Comment: I have had a development. It turns out the reason the keyboard is opening is because the ui-sref link that the user clicks to get to the state (where the keyboard popped up) is in the same position on the screen as the input in the new state. The touch event seems to be carried over to the new state, and registers again causing the input to get focus, thus bringing up the keyboard.

So, the question is now, why is the tap event carried across the state change in IOS?

I may have to make this in to a new post as this is a different thing to my diagnosis in the original post.

Comment: @Reaper Bruh! This is indeed the case for me aswell. Good find. Any chance you found a solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not. In the end the client changed their design (for the umpteenth time) such that the button on the first screen was not overlapping the input on the second.

@MKouhosei came up with a programmatic workaround that might be helpful for you...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and it seems to have something to do with the way the iOS browser sends click events (more here: http://blog.ionic.io/hybrid-apps-and-the-curse-of-the-300ms-delay/)

The way I worked this out was to hide my form on $stateChangeStart and then show the form 400ms later. An slightly better way is to have a transparent div covering everything, that you hide 400ms after $ionicView.enter.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 1000;" ng-hide="showFields" class="ng-hide"></div>
```